# Issue with Angular directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

In the module, I have declared the directive but the `<div>` is not getting highlighted.

test.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input  } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[test]'
})
export class TestDirective {
    @Input() highlightColor:string;
    constructor(private el : ElementRef){
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.highlightColor;
    }
}
```

test.template.html

```
<div test highlightColor="red">directive testing</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Input() highlightColor:string;` is not availabe before change detection in constructor. Use `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook.

```
export class TestDirective {
    @Input() highlightColor:string;
    constructor(private el : ElementRef){ }

    ngOnChanges() {
         this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.highlightColor;
    }
}
```

Or if you know that input will always be a string you can get in the constructor using `@Attribute` without `@Input` like this:

```
export class TestDirective {
    constructor(private el : ElementRef, @Attribute('highlightColor') color){
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like:

```typescript
@HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') @Input() highlightColor:string;
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/BvTmtpv49vuqOQ53ywM4?p=preview)**

Don't forget to import `HostBinding`:

```typescript
import { HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
```